# Slicing and assigning values multi-indexed pandas dataframe of unique sequential indices

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index, setvalue

I want to select and change the value of a dataframe cell. There are 2 indices used for this dataframe: 'datetime' and 'idx'. Both contain labels which are unique and sequential. 'datetime' index has datetime label of datetime type, and 'idx' has integer valued labels.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.date_range("2010-10-01 00:00:00", periods=5, freq='H')
d = {'datetime': dt, 'a': np.arange(len(dt))-1,'b':np.arange(len(dt))+1}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index(keys='datetime',inplace=True,drop=True)
df.sort_index(axis=0,level='datetime',ascending=False,inplace=True)

df.loc[:,'idx'] = np.arange(0, len(df),1)+5
df.set_index('idx',drop=True,inplace=True,append=True)
print(df)
```

'Here is the dataframe:

```
                         a  b
datetime            idx      
2010-10-01 04:00:00 5    3  5
2010-10-01 03:00:00 6    2  4
2010-10-01 02:00:00 7    1  3
2010-10-01 01:00:00 8    0  2
2010-10-01 00:00:00 9   -1  1
```

'Say I want to get the row where idx=5. How do I do that? I could use this:

```
print(df.iloc[0])
```

Then I will get result below:

```
a    3
b    5
Name: (2010-10-01 04:00:00, 5), dtype: int32
```

But I want to access and **set the value** in this cell where idx=5, column='a', **by specifying idx value, and column name 'a'**. How do I do that?

Please advice.

Comment: If your problem is solved then consider accepting MaxU's answer. It's much more detailed.

Comment: Ok, I accepted MaxU's answer. However, I think I will go with your solution as I tested it to be faster (1.28ms vs 2.77ms), and shorter without need for converting the integer to string then concatenating with the 'idx' string for input into the eval function...also, since I will be using this in for-loops.

Comment: Yep. Because xs won't traverse the entire column to search the idx value. It will calculate the hash value of 5 and fetch it in 1 go. The other index  i.e datetime index is too long to write in slicing :|

Comment: @ConanG, why do you want to use it in for-loops? Are you sure it's not possible to use a vectorized approach?

Comment: @ConanG Read piRSquared's comment below my answer. You can't use `set_value` if `idx` is not unique.

Comment: @MaxU, the assignment at each iteration would depend on the previous value assigned. I doubt this type of operation can be vectorized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DatFrame.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method for querying MultiIndex DFs:

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]:
                         a  b
datetime            idx
2010-10-01 04:00:00 5    3  5
2010-10-01 03:00:00 6    2  4
2010-10-01 02:00:00 7    1  3
2010-10-01 01:00:00 8    0  2
2010-10-01 00:00:00 9   -1  1

In [55]: df.query('idx==5')
Out[55]:
                         a  b
datetime            idx
2010-10-01 04:00:00 5    3  5

In [56]: df.query('idx==5')['a']
Out[56]:
datetime             idx
2010-10-01 04:00:00  5      3
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Or you can use [DataFrame.eval()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method if you need to set/update some cells:

```
In [61]: df.loc[df.eval('idx==5'), 'a'] = 100

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
                           a  b
datetime            idx
2010-10-01 04:00:00 5    100  5
2010-10-01 03:00:00 6      2  4
2010-10-01 02:00:00 7      1  3
2010-10-01 01:00:00 8      0  2
2010-10-01 00:00:00 9     -1  1
```

Explanation:

```
In [59]: df.eval('idx==5')
Out[59]:
datetime             idx
2010-10-01 04:00:00  5       True
2010-10-01 03:00:00  6      False
2010-10-01 02:00:00  7      False
2010-10-01 01:00:00  8      False
2010-10-01 00:00:00  9      False
dtype: bool

In [60]: df.loc[df.eval('idx==5')]
Out[60]:
                         a  b
datetime            idx
2010-10-01 04:00:00 5    3  5
```

PS if your original MultiIndex doesn't have names, you can easily set them using [rename_axis()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) method:

```
df.rename_axis(('datetime','idx')).query(...)
```

Alternative (bit more expensive) solution - using `sort_index()` + `pd.IndexSlice[]`:

```
In [106]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,5], ['a']]
...
skipped
...
KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```

so we would need to sort index first:

```
In [107]: df.sort_index().loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,5], ['a']]
Out[107]:
                         a
datetime            idx
2010-10-01 04:00:00 5    3
```

Comment: He needs to change the value of column `a` after query.

Comment: @MYGz, thank you for the hint! I've extended my answer

Answer (score 3):

One more way to do it.

**Select value:**

```
df.xs(5, level=-1)
```

**Set value:**

```
df.set_value(df.xs(5, level=-1).index, 'a', 100)
```

Comment: this works only if `5` is unique in the `MultiIndex`

Comment: @piRSquared Hmm. You are right. He will have to use both the keys in that case. Even eval or any other method won't work in that case. Right?

Comment: This is a limitation with `set_value`.  `set_value` is very fast but only works on single cells.  If `5` is not unique, then `df.xs(5, level=-1).index` won't be a scalar.  assigning with `loc` doesn't have that problem, but is slower.

Answer (score 0):

In case to be used in a loop in a large data set, I realized it is about 20 times faster to extract the columns of the dataframe to pandas Series type first, then continue with the selecting and assigning operations.

Or

Even faster (almost 10000 times faster) to a numpy array, if the index labels happen to be consecutive integers.

MYGz's solution was good, but in my use case in a for-loop, it was too slow to be feasible as these operations took most of the time.