# How to change the values in dataframe in pandas when indices are not unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

Now I want to update the value in RUNS column for KOHLI in IPL with 8000. Is it possible? I understand that indices are not unique and that is why I want to know the answer

Comment: Do not link to code and especially code screenshots. Make code a part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df.eval("index == 'IPL' and Name == 'kohli'"), 'Runs'] = 8000
```

Comment: or `df.loc[(df.index == 'IPL') & (df.Name == 'kohli'), 'Runs'] = 8000`

Comment: BTW, I wasn't aware of how `eval` worked.  My crazy answer universe just got bigger.

Comment: @piRSquared, thank you! I really like `df.eval()` because [it gives us a  very easy way to lookup/update rows in Multi-Index DF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41329585/5741205)